# How to store days of week using bit field?

Tags: php, mysql, database, bit

I’m re-factoring an application, and one of the database tables stores days of the week in columns. Each day can either be “on” or “off”.

The notion of on and off makes me think this data could be more succinctly represented as bits. But I’ve not worked with raw bits as a data type before.

The application is written in PHP. I’ve seen bits used to store header values [here](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/aa64c6c805c45a824ae9a66c42e3267e2e2e621a/Request.php#L33-L39). There are then “helper” constants (`HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL` and `HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL` that act as “pre-configurations” for *all* headers being used, or a sub-set being used for AWS ELB-like environments (where some headers are not sent, so are “off”).

So I have a couple of questions using this data type for representing days of the weeks:

1. How would I store the final bit value in MySQL? As in the column data type, length etc.
2. How would I check a day is “on”? If I have the value `0b0100000`, how do I determine using [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) that Tuesday is “on”?
3. How do I “set” days to persist the value in the database? So if I have checkboxes in the UI that submits the values as an array, how would I convert something like:

```text
Array
(
    [days] => Array
        (
            [Monday] => 0
            [Tuesday] => 1
            [Wednesday] => 0
            [Thursday] => 0
            [Friday] => 0
            [Saturday] => 0
            [Sunday] => 0
        )
)
```

…to a bit value like `0b0100000`, again using bitwise operators?

If someone could point me in the right direction of getting started with working with bit values in PHP, I’d be most grateful!

Comment: What's the benefit of this?   Do you need the space?   It wont make the app faster...and there certainly won't be more days added in the future (which is generally the reason to use the bit flag)

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Thanks for your comment. Wasn’t looking for a speed increase but just felt separate columns for each day was a bit “redundant”, especially when it came to reading and writing their values to the database.

Comment: Usually this would be more applicable if u expected a future release to have like an 8th/9th day of week (which isn't the case of course)...I'd consider what your cost benefit ratio is here since it's already implemented and rethink doing this altogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the decimal values of the selected days. So as a really basic example:

```
/**
 * Keys are ISO-8601 numeric representation
 * of the days of the week
 */
$days = [
    1 => 0b0000001, // Monday    =>  1
    2 => 0b0000010, // Tuesday   =>  2
    3 => 0b0000100, // Wednesday =>  4
    4 => 0b0001000, // Thursday  =>  8
    5 => 0b0010000, // Friday    => 16
    6 => 0b0100000, // Saturday  => 32
    7 => 0b1000000, // Sunday    => 64
];
```

You'd just loop and check if the day's bit is set in the value (bitwise and):

```
// The value you'd store in your database
$mondayToFriday = 31; // 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16

foreach ($days as $n => $v) {
  
    /**
     * Get the day's name using strftime (has locale capability)
     * strtotime("Sunday +n days") would work with ISO-8601 day
     * numbers or PHP's date("w") (0 - 6 / Sunday - Saturday)
     */
    $day = strftime("%A", strtotime("Sunday +{$n} days"));


    echo "{$day}: " . (($v & $mondayToFriday) ? "Y" : "N") . PHP_EOL;

}
```

As for your checkboxes, you could just build the binary string from the state of each day (0 or 1), and convert it to decimal using `bindec()` (the order in which they appear in the array is important, you'd need to ensure that they're correctly mapped to their corresponding day's value).

Given your example input, and the days in this example, the following would work:

```
$dec = bindec(strrev(implode("", $input["days"])));
```

Hopefully that'll push you in the right direction.

#### [Here's an example to play with](https://3v4l.org/R6u1v)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: In that example, if Monday=0...Sunday=6, etc, then (1<<0) is the bit that matches Monday's bit, ... (1<<6)) is Sunday's bit.  The 7 bits can fit in a `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.